# How to Browserify-Shim Angular 2?

Tags: angular, browserify, browserify-shim

Anyone know how to Browserify-Shim Angular 2, while keeping Angular external and not bundling it in the build?

```
//package.json
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./app.js",
  "browserify-shim": {
    "angular2": "global:angular2"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [ "browserify-shim" ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "browserify-shim": "~3.2.0"
  }
}
```

...

```
//app.ts
import {Component, View, bootstrap, NgFor} from 'angular2';
```

Result:

```
TypeError: angular2_1 is undefined
```

Comment: i guess you should add another transform named "tsify" to compile ts file.